# How do I get the Sinatra app instance that's being tested by rack-test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rack, rack-test

I want to get hold of the app instance being tested by rack-test so that I can mock some of its methods. I thought I could simply save the app instance in the `app` method, but for some strange reason that doesn't work. It seems like `rack-test` simply uses the instance to get the class, then creates its own instance.

I've made a test to demonstrate my issue (it requires the gems "sinatra", "rack-test" and "rr" to run):

```
require "sinatra"
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "rack/test"
require "rr"

describe "instantiated app" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    cls = Class.new(Sinatra::Base) do
      get "/foo" do
        $instance_id = self.object_id

        generate_response
      end

      def generate_response
        [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am a response"]
      end
    end

    # Instantiate the actual class, and not a wrapped class made by Sinatra
    @app = cls.new!

    return @app
  end

  it "should have the same object id inside response handlers" do
    get "/foo"

    assert_equal $instance_id, @app.object_id,
      "Expected object IDs to be the same"
  end

  it "should trigger mocked instance methods" do
    mock(@app).generate_response {
      [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am MOCKED"]
    }

    get "/foo"

    assert_equal "I am MOCKED", last_response.body
  end
end
```

How come `rack-test` isn't using the instance I provided? How do I get hold of the instance that `rack-test` is using, so that I can mock the `generate_response` method?

---

#### Update

I have made *no* progress. It turns out `rack-test` creates the tested instance on the fly when the first request is made (i.e. `get("/foo")`), so it's not possible to mock the app instance before then.

I have used rr's `stub.proxy(...)` to intercept `.new`, `.new!` and `.allocate`; and added a puts statement with the instance's class name and `object_id`. I have also added such statements in the tested class' constructor, as well as a request handler.

Here's the output:

```
From constructor: <TestSubject 47378836917780>
Proxy intercepted new! instance: <TestSubject 47378836917780>
Proxy intercepted new instance: <Sinatra::Wrapper 47378838065200>
From request handler: <TestSubject 47378838063980>
```

Notice the object ids. The tested instance (printed from the request handler) never went through `.new` and was never initialized.

So, confusingly, the instance being tested is never created, but somehow exists none the less. My guess was that `allocate` was being used, but the proxy intercept shows that it doesn't. I ran `TestSubject.allocate` myself to verify that the intercept works, and it does.

I also added the `inherited`, `included`, `extended` and `prepended` hooks to the tested class and added print statements, but they were never called. This leaves me completely and utterly stumped as to what kind of horrible black magic rack-test is up to under the hood.

So to summarize: the tested instance is created *on the fly* when the first request is sent. The tested instance is created by fel magic and dodges all attempts to catch it with a hook, so I can find no way to mock it. It almost feels like the author of `rake-test` has gone to extraordinary lengths to make sure the app instance can't be touched during testing.

I am still fumbling around for a solution.

Comment: You can memoize the app by using a let helper method. Read more about it here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it.

The problem, all along, turned out to be `Sinatra::Base.call`. Internally, it does `dup.call!(env)`. In other words, every time you run `call`, Sinatra will duplicate your app instance and send the request to the duplicate, circumventing all mocks and stubs. That explains why none of the life cycle hooks were triggered, since presumably `dup` uses some low level C magic to clone the instance (citation needed.)

`rack-test` doesn't do anything convoluted at all, all it does it call `app()` to retrieve the app, and then call `.call(env)` on the app. All I need to do then, is stub out the `.call` method on my class and make sure Sinatra's magic isn't being inserted anywhere. I can use `.new!` on my app to stop Sinatra from inserting a wrapper and a stack, and I can use `.call!` to call my app without Sinatra duplicating my app instance.

**Note:** I can no longer just create an anonymous class inside the `app` function, since that would create a new class each time `app()` is called and leave me unable to mock it.

Here's the test from the question, updated to work:

```
require "sinatra"
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "rack/test"
require "rr"

describe "sinatra app" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  class TestSubject < Sinatra::Base
    get "/foo" do
      generate_response
    end

    def generate_response
      [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am a response"]
    end
  end

  def app
    return TestSubject
  end

  it "should trigger mocked instance methods" do
    stub(TestSubject).call { |env|
      instance = TestSubject.new!

      mock(instance).generate_response {
        [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am MOCKED"]
      }

      instance.call! env
    }

    get "/foo"

    assert_equal "I am MOCKED", last_response.body
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rack test instantiates new `app` per each request (possibly to avoid collisions and start with a fresh state.) The option here would be to mock the `Sinatra::Base` derived class itself, inside `app`:

```
require "sinatra"
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "rack/test"
require "rr"

describe "instantiated app" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Class.new(Sinatra::Base) do
      get "/foo" do
        generate_response
      end

      def generate_response
        [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am a response"]
      end
    end.prepend(Module.new do # ⇐ HERE
      def generate_response
        [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, "I am MOCKED"]
      end
    end).new!
  end

  it "should trigger mocked instance methods" do
    get "/foo"

    assert_equal "I am MOCKED", last_response.body
  end
end
```

or, to mock `app` method in a whole.

Comment: How does it instantiate the new app? I have tried overriding `new`, `new!` and `allocate` and it's not using any of them

Comment: It [mocks the returned from `app` value](https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/blob/43a3ccffffe541abc6bf18c11e5be920108b4b38/lib/rack/test/methods.rb#L30).

Comment: But how does it create new instances from the `app` value? As I said, I've tried hooking into the class life cycle, but the new instances created by `rake-test` isn't triggering *any* of them.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. On each subsequent request it does call `app`, yielding a new instance. All the requests are [delegated to it](https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/blob/43a3ccffffe541abc6bf18c11e5be920108b4b38/lib/rack/mock_session.rb#L29).

Comment: But if it's that simple, why isn't `#initialize` called on each request?

Comment: `#initialize` is only called *once*, no matter how many test cases and requests I add, and the resulting instance isn't even the one being tested, so there's no point mocking methods on it.

Comment: `#initialize` is called once not because of `rack-test`, but because of [`Sinatra::Base#new!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1477).

Comment: Thanks, looking into it now. I still haven't found a way of mocking the app instance before requests are made to it.

Comment: I believe prepending modules as I have shown in the snippet is the way to go.

Comment: How does that scale to lots of test cases that need to mock the app in different ways though?